# What is the name of the pattern with per-value singletons?

Tags: design-patterns

**I wonder what type of pattern I am using. I am confused between factory, proxy and multiton. Thanks for your responses.**

```
class Base extends Database
    {
        /**
         *  base class that contains common methods through 
         *  out the application, and loading of application configs
         */
    }

    class MyObjectsBase extends Base
    {
        /**
         * base class for my objects
         */
    }

    interface MyInterface
    {
        /**
         * interface methods
         */
    }

    class MyObj1 extends MyObjectsBase implements MyInterface
    {
        /**
         * MyObj1 class
         */
    }

    class MyObj2 extends MyObjectsBase implements  MyInterface
    {
        /**
         * MyObj2 class
         */
    }

    class PatternInQuestion
    {
        private static $singleInstanceOfType = array();


        public static function getInstance ($objType)
        {
            if ( ! array_key_exists($objType, self::$singleInstanceOfType) ) {
                self::$singleInstanceOfType[$objType] = new $objType();
            }

            return self::$singleInstanceOfType[$objType];

        }

    }

    /**
     * Usage :
     */

    $type = 'MyObj2';

    $obj = PatternInQuestion::getInstance($type);
```

I wonder what type of pattern I am using. I am confused between factory, proxy and multiton. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation of the [multiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern) pattern.

> In software engineering, the multiton pattern is a design pattern similar to the singleton, which allows only one instance of a class to be created. *The multiton pattern expands on the singleton concept to manage a map of named instances as key-value pairs.*

Comment: Thank you for the link ref. I find the php example is similar to my case. So I guess it is a multiton. Thanks